# Checking Hard Disks working on Dell ESXi server using SNMP from Linux

Tags: linux, vmware-esxi, dell, snmp

I want to use SNMP, preferably over an SSH tunnel, to check whether the disks in my array are still working. There's 8 hard drives running behind a PERC controller on a Dell 730xd running ESXi v6.

I'm using snmpwalk from a Centos server to query a Dell Server running ESXi (v6). I've installed the Open Manage software on the hypervisor and created a community on there, as well as enabling SNMP and checking the firewall.

I've installed the MIBS from the file VMware-mibs-7.0.0-15924762.zip on the Centos server and can successfully communicate with the server over SNMP using the 2c version of SNMP. I get about 2400 entries returned, including the sizes of the arrays created by the PERC RAID controller. I presume I've not got the right MIBS, but the VMWare website seems to be decaying, with broken links to that sort of things.

It also seems I can't query the server using snmpwalk through an SSH tunnel over port 161. The OpenManage Client software also can't talk to the server using a tunnel over 443 and 1311.

Answer (score 0):

Alright so you have multiple questions in this lets get started from the top.

> SNMP, preferably over an SSH tunnel

Why do you want to put an extra layer of complexity for the SNMP call? I assume you going to make this call rather frequently, I would try to minimalize the amount of packages sent through the link as much as possible. If you want authentication/encryption, I would consider looking into SNMPv3. It supports a wide variety of authentication protocols and also encryption of the traffic. While tunnelling through a different protocol could work, I see no reason why would anyone want to do this.

> Dell Server running ESXi (v6). | I've installed the MIBS from the file VMware-mibs-7.0.0-15924762.zip

If you want to make sure you have the correct MIB list, I would recommend try to match the MIB list with the server that you are running it on. Which exact version of v6 are you running on esxi?

> I get about 2400 entries returned, including the sizes of the arrays created by the PERC RAID controller.

If you do have the sizes of the arrays returned with the snmp walk, then what stops you to just query that one single MIB? I can recommend using python (easysnmp) or telegraf to query this information, then push it to an influxDB, and then you can do all sorts of things with it in the future like plot it in Grafana.